# format date in python datatime

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-datetime

I wanted to format the string last_date to d/m/Y. Without formatting it runs but I need formatting

```
    from datetime import date
    from datetime import datetime
    from datetime import timedelta
    from calendar import monthrange
    data = date.today()
    data_atual = data.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    print(data_atual)


    data_e_hora_atuais = datetime.now()
    fuso_horario = timezone("America/Sao_Paulo")
    data_e_hora_sao_paulo = data_e_hora_atuais.astimezone(fuso_horario)
    data_e_hora = data_e_hora_sao_paulo.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    print(data_e_hora)

    last_date = data.replace(day=monthrange(data_atual.year, data_atual.month))
    last_date_formated = last_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    print(last_date)
```

this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Francisco\PycharmProjects\INSS\MODULOS\buscardados.py", line 17, in <module>
    last_date = data.replace(day=monthrange(data_atual.year, data_atual.month))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
```

Comment: Running your code gives a different error so it's hard to debug.. The `timezone("America/Sao_Paulo")` function is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data_atual` is `string` type. So you can't access any attribute like that.
If you want to access `data_atual.year or month`

You need to cast `string` type to `datetime` object.

Or use `data` instead. e.g. `data.year`, `data.month`